# adding subview of another class

Tags: objective-c, ipad, addsubview

iv created a class with xib so i can access it throughout  my app. The class basically holds a nib with has three uiviews and a few buttons buttons+labels. Now im calling class A (the one with 3 view etc) from classB but every time i addsubview to self.view nothing happens. any help appreciated.

ive done the following in class B.h

```
#import "PlayResultViewController.h"
PlayResultViewController *playResultViewController;
```

in classB.m

```
//viewdidload
playResultViewController = [[PlayResultViewController alloc]init];
//some random method
[placeholderView addSubview:playResultViewController.loseView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the initWithNibName to start with, here are some examples

With a Navigation controller u can use

```
BViewController *bController = [[BViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bController animated:YES];
[bController release];
```

without UInavigation controller you can test with

```
BViewController *bController = [[BViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.view = bController; 
    // or alternatively self.view = bController.view;
    [bController release];
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response, but by making self.view=bcontroller ill be overwriting the calling class's view?

Comment: use addSubview for one or [self.view insertSubview:tdController.view atIndex:1];

Comment: hi, ive got that working, thank you however, im able to see tdController.view appear but when I try to call any of the other views and as i already mentioned i have 3, the do not appear at all. tdController.view1 tdController.view2 or tdController.view3 do not appear at all. Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: never mind that, i realised i had to add tdController.view first in order to add the others to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it which nib to load....

```
playResultViewController = [[PlayResultViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Mynib" bundle:nil];
```